# Block search engines from indexing local search results but not search page

Tags: robots.txt, bingbot

Bingbot keeps indexing search engine result pages so I want to:

- Allow search engines to access everything in general.
- Allow search engines to index the `search/` url.
- Disallow only search queries (*search/?q=example*) without blocking the *search/* URL itself.

Are there any conflicts with the following code in relation to my three stated goals?

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /search/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a canonical link on your search page with the URL of the search page. Then give Google some time to clean-up the mess (up to 6 months if there are many pages or low visited pages to cover it all). All indexed pages with query parameters will be regrouped under the search page and removed from rankings little by little.